# Compile a C program with libpng on Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, linker, libpng

I have a little utility I wrote in C that uses libpng.  Under linux, I just install libpng-dev and do "gcc myapp.c /usr/lib/libpng.so -o myapp".  In Mac OS X, I have the Xcode tools installed, which I believe includes libpng. What do I link against, and do I need to specify an include path for png.h?

Comment: For your Linux command line, you should write `-lpng` instead of using the path to the library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try /usr/X11/include/png.h - you'll find the libs in ../lib ( or /usr/X11/lib ) as well.

**EDIT** Mavericks doesn't appear to have this anymore.  You may need to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) to install libpng.

Comment: On 10.9 Mavericks, this seems to no longer exist.

Comment: on my system it's /opt/X11/lib, however when I create executables, in many macs it fails to find it because they have the library on /usr/X11/lib.

How do you link so that you can satisfy both?
Also, does MacOSX come with libpng? should I just link statically?

Comment: I like static linking since you can control the version of the lib you link against and not worry about what the OS distributes.  There should be a way to specify the DYLIB search paths as well (sort of like what ldconfig does) but I haven't played too much with it.