# Native PNG library on MacOSX (mavericks)

Tags: c, png, jpeg, osx-mavericks, tiff

I need to build an application which can read PNG files. On MacOSX mavericks the `libpng` is not available anymore ([see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5186397/136285)).

Is there any other way to read PNG file on MacOSX (Cocoa / Carbon Framework...). I'd rather stay with the native framework than download and compile a local libpng. I also need to read TIFF and JPEG files, so ideally the native framework would also allow me to read those ? I am using `C` programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect that to be handled by the (aptly named) [`Image I/O`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_intro/ikpg_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH201-TPXREF101) framework. [This page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-SW3) has example code on how to set up an "image source" and load an image from it. I don't think you need to care at the application level whether the image is  PNG or not, the framework abstracts that out.